# Passportjs for shared/remote authentication?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm building a secondary web-app (App1) which essentially consumes a small part of the API of another (closely related) web-app (App2). I'd like to be able to share authentication between the two services, but have App2 do the actual authentication. Users who log in to App1 would be logging in with their App2 credentials, and App1 does not have access to the user database of App2.

Off the cuff, I'm envisioning a really simple system where App1 routes its /login to the /login endpoint of App2, and App2 returns a token that can then be used for further authenticated requests against its API via App1. Is this something that Passportjs supports out of the box/through a strategy? Am I better off using Passportjs or writing my own authentication logic in this case?

Note: one of the restrictions in this case is that App1 has no access to the internals of App2. The only features it has access to are the publicly accessible API endpoints.

Comment: it sounds like you should implement SSO

Comment: @jack.the.ripper - is that possible without access to App2's internals? App1 is essentially a bolt-on without access to anything more than publicly accessible APIs on App2.

Comment: you could use a separate `express.Router()` for both the public facing routes and the private routes. then you could pass both of those as middleware to your server.